# Renaming files by comparing it to JSON list?

Tags: vb.net

I have a big folder with many files in it that need to rename, by comparing it to a list of a JSON output.

Here is a sample of the JSON output:

```
[
{"title":"The Little Hours","year":"2017","imdbid":"tt5666304","scid":"10080"},
{"title":"CarGo","year":"2017","imdbid":"tt6680792","scid":"10079"},
{"title":"My Little Pony: The Movie","year":"2017","imdbid":"tt4131800","scid":"10078"},
{"title":"Amityville: The Awakening","year":"2017","imdbid":"tt1935897","scid":"10077"}
]
```

The actual list has over 10,000 entries. In my folder I have the file names that matches with the **scid**. For example **10080**.mp4. In the JSON list, scid 10080 is equals to the *title* **The Little Hours**

I know how to loop through the entire folder to read the names of the file, but I am stuck on reading this JSON file.

my pseudo code is something like:

```
For each file in (folder)
if file.name = Json.scid then
Rename(file, json.title(of that scid))
```

I'be Googled around but the other JSON examples does not look similar to the JSON output I have.

Comment: I think your best option would be to deserialize your JSON into a list of a custom class, then iterate that list and check if there's any file name matching the `scid`. All you gotta do is create a class with properties matching your JSON string, then deserialize that into a `List(Of yourClass)`. This should give you a hint of how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28975809/3740093

Comment: Going to give this a try, thanks!